# Returning less items

Tags: django

Hi I have a problem during my django-app development. I wanted to add cart feature to my e-commerce website but I have a problem. I get an error `get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 4`!   I bet it is caused by line item = Item.objects.get_or_create(Item)` I have not specified ID and I have no idea how to do it or I should just create slugField and pass there the Slug?

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, *args, **kwargs):
    item = Item.objects.get_or_create(Item)
    order_item,created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(active=True)
    order,created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_user=request.user, 
item=item,
order_items=order_item)
    order.quantity += 1
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Cart updated!")
    return redirect('cart-page')
```

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Order(models.Model):
        order_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
        order_items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
        ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=11)
```

ERROR:

```
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 4!
```

Comment: Could you include the whole error stacktrace to your question?

Comment: Doesn't the error explicitly show the line number that's causing the error? There are several lines that could be triggering the error, and knowing the exact line would narrow down the problem greatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the id field, django will do it for you. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). Also see how the get() method works [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get).